# How to remove the background of an SVG with Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, background-removal

I found a royalty free `SVG` image on the net. I'm experimenting with web design using `SVG`. The problem I'm having is that the `SVG` background is white.

**How do I delete / remove the white background, using Adobe Illustrator?**

Comment: Perhaps this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347298/how-do-i-embed-a-transparent-svg-object-inside-an-html-document

Answer (score 7):

Try the Direct Selection tool (keyboard shortcut A, or the white mouse pointer in the toolbox) and see if you can click it.

If you can't select and erase it, chances are the white "background" isn't a background at all; rather, it's the color of the artboard. It's set as white in Illustrator for obvious reasons, but it's ultimately an arbitrary thing. If you really want to change the artboard color, [you can do that](http://designertoday.com/Tutorials/Illustrator/2054/Changing.the.Artboard.Color.Adobe.Illustrator.Tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a background, you should be able to select and remove it. you can achieve that with many different techniques, one problem with SVGs is that some times they have many complicated layers and groups.

First try an see if you can select it using Direct Selection tool, if it's in a group then double clicking on the object would isolate it, making it possible for you to select it individually.

I don't understand why magic wand tool didn't work for you, if it is the only white color object it should have worked...

Alternatively you can try and find that object from your objects, look in the layer window.

Since it's a royalty free SVG, it would be helpful if you give us a link.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that my "background" was actually a black rectangle that I found in the Layer window.

Answer (score 0):

Simple web-based tool that lets you changes colors of vector image using raster graphics editor

sponk.pl/svg-edit-colors/

Comment: Please explain what you mean or how to use the tool you gave the link.  Giving only a link without explanation is not welcome ...

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't time for explaining it.

My tool has been created 2-3 days ago, u can remove background(or other element) at specifed color by using raster graphics editor.

Also i uploaded tutorial on youtube.

Answer (score -1):

its so simple, if u want to change the background of svg file please first visit to layer palette, there u must select ur path u really want to edit and after select that part(path) in layer panel, click on (small vertical redline box) at bottomleft of ur window it will make ur background transparent and u r done.